# Enclathrated - definition?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, materials, polymers

When discussing the solvent uptake of a metal-organic framework would the correct term be "solvent molecules were enclathrated into the pores"? Despite searching for a definition online I have drawn a blank and its not a term I am familiar with. Having read many papers in polymer chemistry where this term is also used I wonder if I have misunderstood its usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oxford Dictionary does not have an entry for enclathrate, but does for clathrate:

> A compound in which molecules of one component are physically trapped within the crystal structure of another.

Using the word enclathrate should be redundant.

Comment: Thank you :) I know biologists use clatherin for the protein coat around membranes and such ... I find it unusual that there are plenty of papers online with "enclathrated" ... must be an older term I guess?

Comment: No, if it was an old term, the Oxford Dictionary would have it. I'm guessing that somebody felt that `clathrate` was not sufficient for their description and so added the `en` to ensure that the readers would realize how entrapped the compound was.